# Rotate Display (Software Force or Driver Fix?)

Tags: display, rotate

I have an Intel GMA4500 chipset, and in the graphics options it lets me choose the rotation. But it immediately reverts back to "None" I have updated the drivers from Intel's site but still no-go. Is there any clever hacks of software that can let me do this?

I'm on Win7 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do it from the Windows display settings? Right-click on the desktop, choose "Screen Resolution", and under "Orientation", choose "Portrait" to flip the display.

[image: change display orientation]

Comment: No, it just acts the same.

Comment: How immediately? Are you sure you're not missing a confirm box or something?

Comment: Immediately. I'd hit apply the screen would flicker (1/8th of a sec?) like it does when you rotate or change resolution and then there'd be no confirmation box and the rotation says "None"